# Why doesn't this source statement work?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

The file `tmp.sh` contains:

```
func() {
   ls
}
```

If the file is sourced using `source tmp.sh`, the function `func` works fine.

However, if the sourcing is done as `cat tmp.sh | source /dev/stdin` bash complaints:

> -bash: func3: command not found

What is the difference between the two methods of sourcing? From `source`'s perspective there should not be any difference since `/dev/stdin` would also be a file handle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From bash(1): *Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).*

The main shell does not have access to the definitions of its subshells.